# vertical space inside multicols environment

Tags: multicol, vspace

I'm trying to get a vertical space inserted after some text inside a `multicols` environment, such that the next body of text (in bold) sits at the bottom of the page. To make this concrete, imagine 'some text' = clauses of contract, and 'next body of text' = initials. `\vpsace{\fill}` does not do the job. What else should I try?

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \textbf{\lipsum[5][1]}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This does the job, but I have to manually set the number of lines:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}%[\section{TEST} TEST]
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \vspace*{\fill}
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \ \\  
  \textbf{\lipsum[5][1]}
\end{multicols}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems easy, use `\vfill` and `multicol*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
 
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{multicols*}{2}
  \lipsum[1-4]
  \vfill{}
  \textbf{\lipsum[5][1]}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

You may add `\noindent` to suppress the indentation of the last line.

[image: Result]

Comment: Indeed, section 2.2 of the man. Eluded me the first time around. https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/multicol.pdf